# Remove focus from windows form

Tags: winforms

I developed a windows application. In which notification form displays right bottom of the window in every 5 min interval. if notification form opens when i working on notepad/excel, the focus automatically transferred to the windows form. I want to prevent this form focus. Is there any solution?

Comment: so popup windows appears, but you don't want the focus to switch to it but rather stay in place?

Comment: What is the method you using for Show/Hide ?

Comment: simply written this.visible=true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code working fine.. thank you all..

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public extern static int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 cmdShow);

```
    const Int32 SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
    const Int32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
    const Int32 HWND_TOPMOST = -1;

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public extern static bool SetWindowPos(
        IntPtr hWnd, // handle to window
        Int32 hWndInsertAfter, // placement-order handle
        Int32 X, // horizontal position
        Int32 Y, // vertical position
        Int32 cx, // width
        Int32 cy, // height
        Int32 uFlags // window-positioning options
        );
```

and when you display the popup call the below method:

ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);